# how to center google map with input zip code

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I´m trying to center a google map after init to a zipcode from input button

What am doing wrong? can someone give me a solution please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>g</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif';
                font-size:12px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #map {
                width: 75%;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
            }

            #right-panel {
                width: 24%;
                float: left;
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 0.5%;
            }

            #logo_top {
            width: 20%;
            height:5%;
            float: left;
            background-image: url(http://darwin.pytalhost.de/vf_top_LS4.png);
            -moz-background-size:100% 100%; /* Firefox */
            -webkit-background-size:100% 100%; /* Safari, Chrome */
            background-size:100% 100%; /* Opera, IE, W3C Standard */
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            }

        </style>
  </head>

  <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id ="logo_top"></div>
        <form>
            PLZ: <input type="text" name="PLZ" id="PLZ"><br>
            <button onclick="codeAddress(PLZ)">Suchen</button>
        </form>
        <div id="right-panel">
        <br>
        <div id="directions-panel"></div>
        </div>

        <script>        
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'BE'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'BS'
        }
      };    

            var geocoder;

            function initMap() {            
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
                    zoom: 12
                });
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                //eigenes
                var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
                summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('http://darwin.pytalhost.de/create_markers.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label   + '1'               
              });

              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });       

                            //eigenes
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += address   + '<br>';

            });
          });
        }               

      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}

            function codeAddress(zipCode) {
                    geocoder.geocode({
                            'address': zipCode, "componentRestrictions":{"country":"DE"}
                    }, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            map: map,
                                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                                    });
                            } else {
                                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                            }
                    });
            }       

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

for me it´s not that simple how it looks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>g</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif';
                font-size:12px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #map {
                width: 75%;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
            }

            #right-panel {
                width: 24%;
                float: left;
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 0.5%;
            }

            #logo_top {
            width: 20%;
            height:5%;
            float: left;
            background-image: url(http://darwin.pytalhost.de/vf_top_LS4.png);
            -moz-background-size:100% 100%; /* Firefox */
            -webkit-background-size:100% 100%; /* Safari, Chrome */
            background-size:100% 100%; /* Opera, IE, W3C Standard */
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            }

        </style>
  </head>

  <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id ="logo_top"></div>

           <input type="text" name="PLZ" id="PLZ"><br>
            <button onclick="codeAddress()">Suchen</button>


        <div id="right-panel">
        <br>
        <div id="directions-panel"></div>
        </div>

        <script>        
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'BE'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'BS'
        }
      };    
 var map
            var geocoder;

            function initMap() {            
               map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
                    zoom: 12
                });
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                //eigenes
                var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
                summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
        }               

      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = codeAddress;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }


            function codeAddress() {
            var zipCode = document.getElementById("PLZ").innerHTML;
                    geocoder.geocode({
                            'address': zipCode, "componentRestrictions":{"country":"DE"}
                    }, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            map: map,
                                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                                    });
                            } else {
                                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                            }
                    });
            }


    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: many thanks, i don´t know why but
`document.getElementById("PLZ").innerHTML;`
doesn´t work but 
`document.getElementById("PLZ").value;`
does, your solution really helped a lot!